Why are all CSS files in different components loaded in React?
I load multiple components on one page. Of course, I check the condition and then load one of the components!
Home page :
function Home( ) {

    const [pumpCount, setPumpCount] = useState(2);

    useMount(() => {
        console.log("useMount : Home");
        fetch('/home/PumpCount')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("/home/PumpCount : " + response.data);
                //console.log(response);
                setPumpCount(response.data);
                //console.log(pumpCount);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Fetch error:', error);
            });
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Layout>
                <AuthorizeView>
                    {pumpCount === 2 ? <Package2 /> :
                        pumpCount === 3 ? <Package3 /> :
                            pumpCount === 4 ? <Package4 /> :
                                pumpCount === 5 ? <Package5 /> : null}
                </AuthorizeView>
            </Layout>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Home;

I also imported the CSS file of the page into one of the components such as
import '../assets/css/package2.css';

When I run the project,  package2.css and package3.css loaded together. And The style of the page is messed up.
What is the problem? How can I fix it?

There is a possibility that your package[number].css files share similar class names with different stylings. Ideally, you shouldn't be using a global css for that, you should be using css module instead.

The bundler loads all the components you import into the page, including their css files, even if those components are conditionally rendered. Probably this might have caused confusion regarding tree-shaking concepts. Here you can follow two approaches:

Load the components dynamically via React.Lazy React.Suspense
Load your css as modules to ensures that the styles are scoped to the component


I tested two methods, but all the CSS loaded.

If you were able to load css as modules, could you please check how the css names appear in the bundle? Are they unique?
